# React Native : How to pass navigation as props from a functional component to a class component

Tags: react-native, navigation

I want to use `navigation` in a class component, which is not a screen component and does not automatically access `navigation` via `props`, So I have to pass the navigation to it as `props`. But the parent component is a functional component And I used `navigation` hooks in it.
However, how can I use `navigation` in the child component?

**ParentComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {View , TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {useNavigation} from 'react-navigation-hooks';

import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';

const ParentComponent =()=>{
    const {navigate} = useNavigation();
    return(
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate('AnotherScreen')} />
            <ChildComponent />
        </View>
    )
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

**ChildComponent.js**

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import {View , TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

class ChildComponent extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => ???}>
                    <Text>sample text</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default ChildComponent;
```

I use the following dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "native-base": "2.13.8",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.7",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.3",
    "react-navigation-hooks": "^1.1.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.8.1",
  },
```

Your guidance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to navigation prop in parent component simply pass it to the child navigate using the prop.

```
const ParentComponent =()=>{
    const {navigate} = useNavigation();
    return(
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate('AnotherScreen')} />
            <ChildComponent navigate={navigate}/>
        </View>
    )
}

class ChildComponent extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigate('screenname')}>
                    <Text>sample text</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting navigation inside props of the parent component.

- In parent component:

  ```
    const ParentComponent =(props)=>{
        const {navigate} = useNavigation();
        return(
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate('AnotherScreen')} />
                <ChildComponent navigation={props.navigation} />
            </View>
        )
    }
  ```
- In the child component, you can access navigation:

  ```
    class ChildComponent extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SomeOtherScreen')}>
                        <Text>sample text</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            )
        }
    }
  ```